# How do I fix Angular *ngFor DOM node Leak

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, rxjs

I have an application where I poll a server and display the results

I display the results with a *ngFor loop

For whatever reason, the DOM nodes keep stacking up and I'm not sure why

Here is a minimal example:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4k9tab?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

How can I clear out these dom nodes every time I get new data? What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="test" *ngFor="let todo of todos; trackBy: trackByTodo">
  <p class="id">{{todo.title}}</p>
  <p class="status">{{todo.completed}}</p>
</div>
```

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  name = 'Angular';
  todos: Todo[] = [];
  timer: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get new data every 2 seconds
    if (!this.timer) {
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.http.get<Todo[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").subscribe(res => { this.todos = res; });

      }, 10000);
    }

  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
}
```

Here is Chrome's performance monitor (F12 -> Performance Monitor)
[image]

Comment: need to put your code in your question

Comment: you hvaen't reproduced the issue in the stackblitz. viewing the performance monitor there, dom nodes holds steady. Nothing looks overtly incorrect in your example.

Comment: When I run it, dom nodes are growing as you see in the picture. I am running Chrome 84.0.4147.135

Comment: the code in that stackblitz and in this answer doesn't produce the issue you're seeing. something else must be going on that isn't here.

Comment: You must be viewing it wrong. Click on the url on the mini-chrome browser in the stackblitz and open that up so it's a separate page with no editor. https://angular-4k9tab.stackblitz.io/ Then look at the dom nodes. They keep increasing every 10s (when I make a new call)

Comment: I'm not viewing it wrong, you're interpreting it wrong. the browser garbage collects when it feels it needs to, the reason it's not collecting immediately in the simple app case but is in the stackblitz case is because it doesn't need to in the simple case. forcing garbage collection in the performance tab resets everything to what you'd expect, therefor, there is not a memory leak, as leaks are elements that can't be collected due to hanging references.

Comment: This is almost the same exact thing as I'm doing in my production environment. When you view the memory the tab takes after a day, its around 800mb. The DOM Nodes are in the hundred thousands. The garbage collector is not collecting all the garbage

Comment: click the force collection button, do they go away? if they do, then you don't have a memory leak. if they don't go away, you have a memory leak. if you have a memory leak, then you are doing something very different than what you have in this simple example.

Comment: Okay, I see the DOM nodes decrease when the garbage collector runs. This doesn't appear to be the case on my client computers, since they tend to run out of memory at the end of the day. There really isn't much of a difference between this example and my app, other a lot more styling. Is there a way to for the GC to run?

Comment: no, the collector runs according to the browser's algorithm.

Comment: I've had the exact same issue and it's affecting the app I'm working on pretty badly https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20007#issuecomment-682831198 That said in my case it's because I've got `formControlName`. In your case, have a look into https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29053 or https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36878 or https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36590 ...

Comment: I would add a `trackBy`. You seem to have an id field in your `Todo` interface: use it. In your example here there is a reference to `trackByTodo`, which is not in the code. On StackBlitz, there is no trackBy. *If Angular doesn't know how to reuse DOM nodes, it will discard and recreate the full list every time*. Even in case the DOM nodes are properly garbage collected, it's still a lot of useless work. I'm inclined to suggest everyone should always be using trackBy.

Comment: I will try that! thank you @A.Chiesa